# Add new device to provisioning profile automatically managed by Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, udid

I've gt a question regarding Xcode automatically manage signing. Lets say my client wanted to add new device UDID so that device can be used for testing the app. I then added the device UDID in developer.apple.com. Now how do I confirm that the new device is already added to the provisioning profile that is automatically managed by Xcode?

I'm not in possession of the physical device, only the UDID. I'm using Xcode 8.3

Answer (score 1):

Once you added the `UDID` to `Devices`, you can go to your project's `Provisioning Profile`, then you can see the devices amount, if it is not correct, you can click `Edit` to select the device.

[image: device amount of you provisioning file]

[image: select device]

Answer (score 1):

If you're distributing your project via adhoc, then as you already know, UDIDs of the devices that will need to install your project will need to be registered to the `distribution provisioning profile` on developer.apple.com.

> Now how do I confirm that the new device is already added to the provisioning profile that is automatically managed by Xcode?

Go to your Xcode and to your Project's General settings. Check the `Signing` section and click on the `Provisioning Profile` **i** button. You will see the devices included in that `provisioning profile`.

[image]

Comment: Is it just me or the devices are no longer listed there?